# I am using Python to implement linear regression on some dataset, but on this step I am continously getting this error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I wrote this linear regression code and now it is giving me an error:

> at def iterate_weights function.error = index 200 is out of bounds for
>   axis 0 with size 200

I don't know what is wrong. Also when I am uploading my weights they are coming the same as above which I chose at random. I am using Jupyter notebook.

Are there any mistakes?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



#importing dataset
data = pd.read_csv('F:\WOC\linearreg.csv')
print(data.shape)
data.head()
data_arr = np.genfromtxt("F:\WOC\linearreg.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
print(data_arr)


# In[3]:


#collecting x and y
x_train = data_arr[:,1:4]
y_train = data_arr[:,4:5]
print(x_train)
print(y_train)


# In[4]:


weights_shape = y_train.shape
print(weights_shape)
r,c = x_train.shape
print(r,c)
w = np.random.randn(c,1)
w_num = len(w)
print(w)


# In[5]:


h = np.dot(x_train,w)
def cost_function():
    print(h)
    j = (1/2*r)*((h-y_train)**2)
    print('j',j)
cost_function()




# In[6]:


def iterate_weights():
    L=0.01
    iterations = 1000
    for iterations_proceed in range(1,1001):
        for i in range(w_num):
            for m in range(1,201):
                w[i,0] = w[i,0]-L*((1/r)*(sum(h-y_train)*(x_train[m,i])))  
print(w)
iterate_weights()



# In[7]:

h = np.dot(x_train,w)
def cost_function1():
    j = np.sum((1/2*r)*((h-y_train)**2))
    print(j)
```

Comment: Python lists start with element zero, not element one. For a list with 200 elements, use range(200) which yields 0 through 199 for indexing the array. I think that is the problem, that all list and array indexes start at 0.

Comment: What steps did you take to debug this?  `index 200 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200`.  Which line and variable is being indexed like this?  `foo[200,?]`, where `foo` has a shape `(200,?)`.  Have you experimented with indexing an array like that?  Why the difference between the `i` range and `m` one?  Is that intentional?